# solana-validator sync

Tags: validator

when the validator does not fully keep up with the latest block, the rpc service is not enabled. How can I check the progress of synchronization at this time? This entry keeps appearing in the log:

```
net-stats-validator in_datagrams_delta=0i no_ports_delta=0i in_errors_delta=0i out_datagrams_delta=0i rcvbuf_errors_delta=0i sndbuf_errors_delta=0i in_csum_errors_delta=0i ignored_multi_delta=0i in_errors=17173933i rcvbuf_errors=17173933i sndbuf_errors=0i rx_bytes_delta=66i rx_packets_delta=1i rx_errs_delta=0i rx_drops_delta=0i rx_fifo_delta=0i rx_frame_delta=0i tx_bytes_delta=702i tx_packets_delta=1i tx_errs_delta=0i tx_drops_delta=0i tx_fifo_delta=0i tx_colls_delta=0i
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the status of your node catching up to the cluster, you have two options:

- `solana catchup <NODE_PUBKEY>`: tells how far you are from the tip of the network, more info at https://docs.solana.com/validator/get-started/setup-a-validator#solana-catchup
- `getHealth` RPC endpoint: gives the distance from the tip of the cluster, more info at https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gethealth